# calculating unique square mxm matrices in a large square MxM matrix

Tags: c++, matrix

I'm facing a problem ...
I have a square matrix (say 6x6) and it is required to calculate all unique (unrepeated) smaller square matrices ...

(NOTE: to find the number of unrepeated unique rxr square matrix inside a big square NxN matrix we can use "ncr" ex: 6x6 matrix has 6c2 smaller 2x2 unique matrices which are 15)

so the required is : 
I have 6x6 matrix , and i want to get all possible combinations for calculating all unrepeated 5x5, 4x4, .... to 2x2 matrices.

---

here is a part of my code which is responsible for extracting unique square matrices , starting from 3x3 to NxN

---

```
 string line;
        int normalCnt = 0;
        int lastCnt = 12;
        for(int a=2; a<k; a++){
            for(int b=1; b<=k-a; b++){
                for(int c=b+a; c<=k; c++){
                    line = "det_"+static_cast<ostringstream*>( &(ostringstream() << a+1) )->str()+"x"+static_cast<ostringstream*>( &(ostringstream() << a+1) )->str()
                        +"#("+static_cast<ostringstream*>( &(ostringstream() << parameter) )->str()+") U_"+static_cast<ostringstream*>( &(ostringstream() << lastCnt++) )->str()
                        +"(";
                    for(int d=b; d<b+a; d++)
                        line = line + "c"+static_cast<ostringstream*>( &(ostringstream() << k-a) )->str()+static_cast<ostringstream*>( &(ostringstream() << d) )->str()+"_i,";
                    line = line + "c"+static_cast<ostringstream*>( &(ostringstream() << k-a) )->str()+static_cast<ostringstream*>( &(ostringstream() << c) )->str()+"_i,";
                    for(int e=b; e<=b+a; e++)
                        line = line + "mat_"+static_cast<ostringstream*>( &(ostringstream() << a) )->str()+"x"+static_cast<ostringstream*>( &(ostringstream() << a) )->str()+"["
                        +static_cast<ostringstream*>( &(ostringstream() << normalCnt++) )->str()+"],";
                    line = line + "mat_"+static_cast<ostringstream*>( &(ostringstream() << a+1) )->str()+"x"+static_cast<ostringstream*>( &(ostringstream() << a+1) )->str()+"["
                        +static_cast<ostringstream*>( &(ostringstream() << lastCnt) )->str()+"]);";
                    myfile<<line<<"\n";
                }
            }
            normalCnt -= lastCnt;
            myfile << "\n";
        }
```

let me explain what is required exactly ...
if i have a 6x6 matrix , it has six 5x5 unique square matrices, and each 5x5 matrix has five 4x4 unique matrices ..... if i directly can find the unique 4x4 matrices in a 6x6 one, i can pass them simply to another function for calculating a 5x5 matrix without repeating those 4x4 matrices, and so on.
Here i am using for loops inside each other which :

- may cause a stack overflow in memory
- increase complexity for larger matrix size

I want to know if there is another alogorithm which may use recursion or other technique for solving this problem

Comment: To answer your question, yes there is an algorithm to solve this problem. And yes, you can implement that algorithm in C++. Please show what you've tried and maybe someone can help you fix it if it's broken.

Comment: ok i have edited the question ... have a look

Comment: help !! help !! help !!